# Hide JInternalFrame from JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jinternalframe

I'm building a JPanel and it is given to a JInternalFrame. Now I want that if someone clicks on the `X` button of the JInternalFrame it is hidden, not closed. The Problem is that I have to implement this function in the JPanel and I don't have access to the JInternalFrame.

Is this possible?

I know from the JInternalFrame it can be realized with `setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);` but I don't know how to do it from the JPanel. Of course I searched in SO but I did not found anything that fits for my case.

Another Question, just for understanding: what is happening when you click on the `X` button? Is the `dispose()` function called? I'm new to Java Swing and interested how it works.

Comment: *Is this possible?* No, it is not.  Yes, the dispose method is called when the user clicks on the "X".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I don't know how to do it from the JPanel

You can use the `SwingUtilities` class to find the parent container.

Something like:

```
JInternalFrame frame = (JInternalFrame)SwingUtilities.ancestorOfClass(JInternalFrame.class, thePanel);
```

Comment: When I initialize the Panel, it doesn't has a parent Container so I get a NullPointerException. I can't use it at afterwards, but thanks

Comment: @Ludy, that is correct. You should NOT be executing that code when you create the components. The above code is executed in the `ActionListener` you add to the button that you add to your panel.

Comment: now I found a way how to use your line. An AncestorListener is working for me. BTW should I post my solution?